# How to create a md5-file for every folder in a drive recursively?

Tags: bash, shell-script, checksum, hashsum

I'm searching for a script which creates a md5 chechsum file for every single folder inside drive recursivley?

I do have a copy of md5deep on my machine but I'm not that good in scripting bash.

Comment: Why do you need a script if you have md5deep, why not just `md5deep -r [folder name]`?

Comment: Because md5deep creates one file with all checksums. What I want is a md5-file for every single file. For Example: document1.doc document1.md5, document2.doc document2.md5 and so on.

Comment: That's an unusual thing to want - most people go with either one file with all checksums, or one file per directory with all the files in that directory.

Comment: So it's not possible?

Comment: Similair to what integritychecker on mac os x does: http://diglloydtools.com/integritychecker.html

Comment: It just seems strange to me - why do you want all those files? - note that in your link it says integritychecker creates one file per directory, not per file. But md5deep is designed to do the verification step with a single file that lists everything, and I don't understand why you don't want that. I guess what I'm asking is - what are you going to do with all those files?

Comment: Yeah, you are right I got it wrong. I thought this way I could checksum single files rather than to checksum the whole content of the folder.

Comment: So what do I do if I want md5deep to create single md5-file for every folder in a specific drive?

Answer (score 5):

To get a .md5 file for any files under a specific directory, you can use the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 1 ] ; then
        echo "Usage $0 [directory]" 
        exit 1
fi
find $1 -type f  -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
    (
    cd "$(dirname "$file")"
    filename="$(basename "$file")"
    md5sum "$filename" > "$filename".md5
    )
done
```

In `zsh`, the same for all files under the current directory can be done with the one-line command (includes files starting with a dot):

```
for i in **/*(/D) ; do ( cd $i ; for j in *(.D) ; do md5sum $j > $j.md5 ; done ) ; done
```

Comment: @la_tristesse I rewrote my answer. Please be more specific in your questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Necromancy sure, but I know how we love 1 line-ers

```
#find / -type f  -exec md5sum {} + > CheckSums
```

personally I would use sha512sum, and limit to /home or something but if you want to checksum root then go for it.